# Database creation and query

Tags: database

So I have to created a recipe website and HTML-CSS is mainly my forte. I need a database to search through over a 100 recipes and mainly sort them,by author, apart from the other sorting orders. I don't want to use a CMS like Joomla. How do I start about?

Do I store the entire recipe(with a picture or two), into the database, or only a link to the recipe?

Secondly, the client would be updating the website as well, is there any way to simplify the process for the client who has absolutely no knowledge of adding into a database.

Comment: use a CMS its easier for all of us.

Comment: my only issue with a CMS is i have my own style and converting css-html into a joomla/other template is a big pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to do some server-side scripting. If you don't want to use a CMS or framework, you (or someone else) will have to write the code for all of the site.

DB design pointers:

- Store the recipe in the database, along with the author, etc.
- Don't store the pictures in the db, even though it's easy enough to do. Better store than in a field in the db, called 'filename' or something which stores the path of the images on the server.
- For the client - you will need to build a backend/admin page(s) with 'forms' for the client to upload (add), update and delete recipes and pictures.

Comment: Thanks!And do i store the entire recipe in the database or what?

Comment: Yes, store the entire recipe. May require a [`TEXT` field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html), if you're using MySQL.

Comment: One more question.Now i'll just be displaying  the names of the recipes on a particular page,i'll be displaying the entire recipe along with a picture on individual pages.How do i work out the html linking and displaying in a new page and everything?Also i want to add a comment system on that page which will display the recipe

Comment: [You've asked that as a separate question a got an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330564/retrieving-id-from-database-displayed-and-passing-onto-other-page).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need save pictures into database. See [database model](http://www.daveegerton.com/assets/images/database-schema-prestashop.png) of Prestashop(see only relative to images because are various tables), for example.

Regards and good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You can add pictures into data bases as well. For that you can always reduce the size of the images before inserting into database.
For database, you can use php or javascript. Both provide easy way of accessing database.
Javascript even has inbuilt transaction commit and rollback feature.

Comment: Bullshit. JavaScript and transactions only for client-side databases (HTML5). You seem not even to understand the difference between client- and server-side.