# Retrieving id from database displayed and passing onto other page

Tags: html

I'm displaying the contents of a database on a particular page(recipe names).
I'd like each recipe to be a link which opens to another page. I understand I would have to obtain the recipe id for that particular recipe, pass the id to another page and print the recipe contents onto that page. I would like to know how to retrieve the unique recipe id of a particular recipe **ON BEING CLICKED** upon mainly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are **displaying the contents of a database on a particular page**, then definitely you are using a server side scripting like like `ASP` or `PHP` or some `JavaScript` + `AJAX`. I am quite unclear about that. But for your question, I can tell you one thing that, if, suppose you are using PHP, then you may display the link as;

```
echo '<a href="yourpage.php?recipeid='.$recepeid.'">'.$recipiename.'</a>';
```

where `$recipeid` is the variable carrying recipe id and `$recipiename` is the name of your recipe. In your PHP file (`yourpage.php`), you may catch this data like `$_GET["recipeid"]`

You may try a Google search for tutorials.

Use;

```
$strLink = '<a href="recipedisp.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$strName.'</a>';
echo "<li>".$strLink."</li>";
```

Don't use spaces.

Comment: I tried that.Here is my code to echo :     $strLink = "<a href = 'recipedisp.php?id = ".$row['id']."'>" . $strName . "</a>";

     // List link
    echo "<li>" . $strLink . "</li>"; BUT the end URL looks like http://localhost/recipedisp.php?id%20=%2012 so the GET method doesnt really pick anything up....

Comment: you're welcome :) . Don't forget to mark this as accepted answer by clicking tick / check mark icon.

Answer (score 0):

You just make the id part auf the URL the recipe link points to.

```
<a href="/recipe/23">Iced Water</a>
```

Would be a link pointing to the recipe with ID 23. Since the url is available on the server side you are all set.